# Configuring OpenTelemetry Collector to Export Zipkin traces

Tags: zipkin, jaeger, open-telemetry

I'm attempting to configure the open telemetry collector in Kubernetes. I took the jaeger all in one deployment which is here: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.22/opentelemetry/ and ported it to kubernete running on my minikube.

The problem is I can't seem to get the open telemetry collector to receive the jaeger traces and send it to my proxy container. My jaeger all in one app seems to be working in my minikube instance. Traces are being sent through the hot rap app and I can view the traces in the jaeger UI.

[image]

My open telemetry collector looks like the following:

```
receivers:
  jaeger:
    protocols:
       grpc:
         endpoint: 0.0.0.0:14250
       thrift_compact:
         endpoint: 0.0.0.0:6831
       thrift_http:
         endpoint: 0.0.0.0:14268
         logging:
            loglevel: debug
   
exporters:
  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://proxy.collector-agent.svc.cluster.local:80/v1/observations/api/v2/spans"
    insecure: true
  logging:
      loglevel: debug

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [jaeger] 
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [zipkin]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging]
```

It doesn't seem that the open-tel collector is even receiving the jaeger traces. The logs from the container are below..

```
dev-MacBook-Pro otel-agent % kubectl logs otel-collector-6c4db7687c-h9pm9 
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.394Z    info    service/service.go:411  Starting OpenTelemetry Collector... {"Version": "v0.22.0-7-gc8bc12e3", "GitHash": "c8bc12e3", "NumCPU": 2}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.404Z    info    service/service.go:593  Using memory ballast    {"MiBs": 683}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.404Z    info    service/service.go:255  Setting up own telemetry...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.406Z    info    service/telemetry.go:102    Serving Prometheus metrics  {"address": ":8888", "level": 0, "service.instance.id": "85884852-3e34-4b13-b24e-03d7e9f49868"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.406Z    info    service/service.go:292  Loading configuration...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.409Z    info    service/service.go:303  Applying configuration...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.409Z    info    service/service.go:324  Starting extensions...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.409Z    info    builder/extensions_builder.go:53    Extension is starting...    {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "health_check", "component_name": "health_check"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.409Z    info    healthcheckextension/healthcheckextension.go:40 Starting health_check extension {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "health_check", "component_name": "health_check", "config": {"TypeVal":"health_check","NameVal":"health_check","Port":13133}}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.410Z    info    builder/extensions_builder.go:59    Extension started.  {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "health_check", "component_name": "health_check"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.410Z    info    builder/extensions_builder.go:53    Extension is starting...    {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "zpages", "component_name": "zpages"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.410Z    info    zpagesextension/zpagesextension.go:42   Register Host's zPages  {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "zpages", "component_name": "zpages"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.413Z    info    zpagesextension/zpagesextension.go:55   Starting zPages extension   {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "zpages", "component_name": "zpages", "config": {"TypeVal":"zpages","NameVal":"zpages","Endpoint":"localhost:55679"}}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.413Z    info    builder/extensions_builder.go:59    Extension started.  {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "zpages", "component_name": "zpages"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/exporters_builder.go:302    Exporter is enabled.    {"component_kind": "exporter", "exporter": "zipkin"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    service/service.go:339  Starting exporters...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/exporters_builder.go:92 Exporter is starting... {"component_kind": "exporter", "component_type": "zipkin", "component_name": "zipkin"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/exporters_builder.go:97 Exporter started.   {"component_kind": "exporter", "component_type": "zipkin", "component_name": "zipkin"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    memorylimiter/memorylimiter.go:108  Memory limiter configured   {"component_kind": "processor", "component_type": "memory_limiter", "component_name": "memory_limiter", "limit_mib": 1572864000, "spike_limit_mib": 536870912, "check_interval": 5}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/pipelines_builder.go:203    Pipeline is enabled.    {"pipeline_name": "traces/1", "pipeline_datatype": "traces"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    service/service.go:352  Starting processors...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/pipelines_builder.go:51 Pipeline is starting... {"pipeline_name": "traces/1", "pipeline_datatype": "traces"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/pipelines_builder.go:61 Pipeline is started.    {"pipeline_name": "traces/1", "pipeline_datatype": "traces"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/receivers_builder.go:230    Receiver is enabled.    {"component_kind": "receiver", "component_type": "jaeger", "component_name": "jaeger", "datatype": "traces"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/receivers_builder.go:105    Ignoring receiver as it is not used by any pipeline {"component_kind": "receiver", "component_type": "zipkin", "component_name": "zipkin", "receiver": "zipkin"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    service/service.go:364  Starting receivers...
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.414Z    info    builder/receivers_builder.go:70 Receiver is starting... {"component_kind": "receiver", "component_type": "jaeger", "component_name": "jaeger"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.415Z    info    static/strategy_store.go:201    No sampling strategies provided or URL is unavailable, using defaults   {"component_kind": "receiver", "component_type": "jaeger", "component_name": "jaeger"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.415Z    info    builder/receivers_builder.go:75 Receiver started.   {"component_kind": "receiver", "component_type": "jaeger", "component_name": "jaeger"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.415Z    info    healthcheck/handler.go:128  Health Check state change   {"component_kind": "extension", "component_type": "health_check", "component_name": "health_check", "status": "ready"}
    2021-03-10T16:53:39.415Z    info    service/service.go:267  Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data.
```

Even when I send a ton of jaeger traces nothing ever seems to be received by the collector. Is there a way to debug further or a configuration I'm missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.